# PHP Postgres default connection

Tags: php, database, postgresql

pg_query and pg_query_params in PHP can be executed without specifying a connection resource in the arguments' list, so PHP will use the last connection opene by pg_connect.

Is there a way to retrieve the default connection string that PHP will use intead of trying to figure out where it is coming from across a couple of PHP files? Something like get_default_dbConnection()?

Thanks.

Comment: Might be worth giving `pg-options()` a try, but I'm not very sure what data it will give you (nor what data you're actually after).

Answer (score 2):

That doesnt mean that there is a default connection string, but that you dont have to provide a param that references the connection. Check out the example on [php: pg_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php)

```
$conn = pg_pconnect("dbname=publisher");
if (!$conn) {
  echo "An error occured.\n";
  exit;
}

$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT author, email FROM authors");
if (!$result) {
  echo "An error occured.\n";
  exit;
}
```

In this example there is `$conn = pg_pconnect("dbname=publisher")` and in the call to `pg_query` they pass a long `$conn`. That is the connection reference. Now you could also just use

```
$conn = pg_pconnect("dbname=publisher");
$result = pg_query("SELECT author, email FROM authors");
```

`pg_query` will now automatically use the last opened connection (which is $conn)

Update:

You cannot get the resource, `PHP` uses an internal method `php_pgsql_get_default_link` to get the default connection but will not return it anywhere (See `php-5.4.9\ext\pgsql\pgsql.c` in the source).

You can get information on the database name or user using [pg_dbname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-dbname.php) or [pg_parameter_status](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-parameter-status.php)

Comment: Assuming that in a PHP file you encounter the line:
$result = pg_query("SELECT author, email FROM authors");

what I am asking is how to get the connection resource used in the pg_query without having to trace back the code to find the last pg_connect...

Comment: You cannot get the resource, `PHP` uses an internal method `php_pgsql_get_default_link` to get the default connection but will not return it anywhere (php-5.4.9\ext\pgsql\pgsql.c). You can get information on the database name or user using `pg_dbname` or `pg_parameter_status`